# Get the detached object from the session in the Hibernate events PostLoadEvent and PostUpdateEvent

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I have an entity which has transient fields, after the merge / load i loose all the values of these transient fields in the returned managed object.

What i want to do , is to copy the values of the transient fields from the detached object to the managed object.

The solution that i want to follow is based on the events in Hibernate, but i only have access to the detached object (the original entity) in the MergeEventListener and not in the PostUpdateEventListener and PostLoadEventListener .

Do you have any suggestion to find a solution to this issue ?

Thank you

Comment: are you copying the transient field value to a persistent field? if so, why cant you copy the value in the detached entity itself before merging?

Comment: No , I want to copy the value of the transient field from the detached object to the managed object, i don't want to recalculate the value of that field after receiving the managed object. I want that this kind of behavior be generic, so i want to develop a Listener based on the Hibernate Events , to copye the values of the transient field from the original object the managed one .